# How to get "Theorems 1 to 6" when Theorems 3 to 6 are in the appendix rather than in the main body?

Tags: cleveref, amsthm

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage{amsthm}

% THEOREM DEFINITION

\makeatletter

\newtheoremstyle{style1}{\topsep}{}{\itshape}{}{\scshape}{}{ }{\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2}.\thmnote{#3}}
\theoremstyle{style1}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[]

\makeatother

% REFERENCES SETTINGS

\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}

%@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
    Fancy abstract which mentions \cref{t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6}
\end{abstract}

\begin{theorem}\label{t1}
    Fancy theorem 1.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\label{t2}
    Fancy theorem 2.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\label{t3}
    Fancy theorem 3.
\end{theorem}

\appendix
\section{Appendix}

\begin{theorem}\label{t4}
    Fancy theorem 4.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\label{t5}
    Fancy theorem 5.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\label{t6}
    Fancy theorem 6.
\end{theorem}
    
\end{document}
```

As you can see in the output below, I obtain "Theorems 1 to 3 and 4 to 6" instead of "Theorems 1 to 6" just because Theorems 3 to 6 are in the Appendix and not in the main body of the text.

**How can I get "Theorems 1 to 6" rather than "Theorems 1 to 3 and 4 to 6" without moving those theorems to the main body?**

[image]

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: You can use `\makeatletter\cref@old@appendix\makeatother` instead of `\appendix`. However, since `cleveref` must have modified `\appendix` for a reason, there might be some other problems with this.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it does not work.

Comment: This works in your current MWE. Can you provide an example where it fails to work?

Comment: Alternatively, in the preamble `\AtBeginDocument{\let\appendix\cref@old@appendix}` (within `\makeatletter .. \makeatother`).

Comment: @Jinwen Thank you for your comment. While your approaches do work in the MWE I provided, it alters the numbering of my sections against my will.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you for your comment. It indeed works!

Comment: As @Jinwen notes, this solution will mess up other things. For example, any `\cref` to a section in the appendix will show up as "Section *X*" instead of "Appendix *X*" etc. So at best it is a hack that might be useful in your specific case, but is really not a general solution. Personally I would probably just not apply the patch, and deal with this particular reference manually without using `\cref`.